# Explaining the functions of cable gateway with wirelessAP device

Tags: networking, router, switch, gateway

Theoretical question.
Let's say I have a device that is described as a standard home cable (DOCSIS) gateway with wirelessAP to which I connect a number of end devices.

The end devices are directly connected with this device via wireless.

Can we say that this device:

1. acts as a router and separates the home network of mine from the Internet?
2. acts as if it has a switch between this router and my end devices?

Link to manual: http://setuprouter.com/router/technicolor/tc7200-u/manual-1685.pdf

Comment: 1/ Yes 2/ No. Cable Modems with built-in Wireless Access typically include router and firewall functionality. Refer to your device documentation for more information.

Comment: So this device immediately sends (routs) IP packets to right end device without checking Link layer data (addresses)?

Comment: The link layer data is used by the built in router ... that's what routers do ...

Comment: Please do some research on how modems, routers, switches and bridges work.

Comment: I did but I'm not clear with the concepts. I wanted to say this cable gateway routes data based only on IP address not MAC address. Is this correct?

Comment: I've no idea. Look in the manual for your device as I've already asked you to do.

Comment: I've checked the manual and I'm not closer to the answer: http://setuprouter.com/router/technicolor/tc7200-u/manual-1685.pdf.
So are the two possibilities: A) routes directly by IP addresses, B) has a built in switch that routes by MAC? Or am I getting it wrong? If these are the only two options I'm satisfied.

Comment: The answer is both - it can both filter on MAC addresses and on IP addresses. This is clearly explained in the manual on p34 and p35. :)

Answer (score 2):

> Can we say that this device:
>   1. acts as a router and separates the home network of mine from the Internet?

Yes, but it's more than a router. There doesn't appear to be a way to make it do plain IP routing between two subnets. So it's more properly referred to as an *NAPT gateway* (NAPT = Network Address *and Port* Translation, which is what people mean 99% of the time they write *NAT*).

> 2. acts as if it has a switch between this router and my end devices?

Yes. In this kind of device, the LAN and WLAN ports are bridged (switched) together. You can think of your box like this:

```
                               +--------+---[2.4GHz Wi-Fi AP]
+-------+   +--------------+   |        +---[5GHz Wi-Fi AP]
| modem +---+ NAPT gateway +---+ switch +---LAN1
+-------+   +--------------+   |        +---LAN2
                               |        +---LAN3
                               +--------+---LAN4
```

While we're being so precise, note that a Wi-Fi AP is much more like an Ethernet hub (repeater) than a switch, because it does not allow full-duplex operation. So it's as if all of your 2.4GHz devices are on one "hub", and all your 5GHz devices are on another "hub", and those two hubs are connected to the same switch as your LAN ports.

Also note that in many home gateway designs, it's slightly more complex than this, but in a mostly transparent way. For example, the Wi-Fi AP radios may not be connected to the same physical switch chip as the LAN ports, but the LAN switch and the AP radios are bridged (switched) together via software switching in the main SOC (CPU) that runs the whole gateway.

Answer (score 0):

The device is functionally identical to having a regular wireless router (which is a type of AP) with it's upstream port connected to a regular DOCSIS modem (and in fact, most such combined Modem/AP devices are in fact such a combination, but using traces on a circuit board instead of a physical Ethernet cable).

From a network topology perspective, it is both:

1. A NAT router (all internal clients appear externally as one client with whatever your external IP address is), just like almost all consumer access points (in contrast to many corporate AP's, which are typically run as 802.3 to 802.11 bridges, not routers).
2. A layer 3 gateway (because it's converting from IEE 802.11 and/or IEEE 802.3 signaling and framing to ITU-T J.112/J.122/J.222 signaling and framing), just like any modem that provides an ethernet connection that you connect your computer to.